# How to find out what process is writing to STDOUT?

Tags: process, debugging, stdout, open-files, trace

I have two instances of a process running. One of them is "frEAkIng oUT!" and printing errors non stop to STDOUT.

I want to kill the broken process but I have to make sure I don't terminate the wrong one. They were both started about at the same time and using `top` I can see they both use about the same amount of memory and CPU. I can't seem to find anything that points to which process is behaving badly.

The safest thing would be to figure out which process/pid is writing to STDOUT.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: _Writing to stdout_ would mean _writing to its file descriptor 1_ ((of the process in question) which may be anything like a terminal or `/dev/null`). Are you sure you don't mean _a particular file_ instead (like a terminal device, or a log file...)?

Comment: If they were both started in the same shell then they're both writing to STDOUT, so pinning this will not help you identify which of the 2 to kill. Jofel's method is likely what you're looking for.

Comment: What he really means is _which one is producing output on the terminal_.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On Linux, assuming you want to know what is writing to the same resource as your shell's stdout is connected to, you could do:

```
strace -fe write $(lsof -t "/proc/$$/fd/1" | sed 's/^/-p/')
```

That would report the `write()` system calls (on any file descriptor) of every process that have at least one file descriptor open on the same file as fd 1 of your shell.

Comment: That is what I had in mind initially, I will try both methods thanks to you both.

Answer (score 25):

You can stop both processing by sending them SIGSTOP (replace pid1 and pid2 by the actual [PIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) or use `killall` and the application name):

```
kill -SIGSTOP pid1 pid2
```

The printing on the terminal (or wherever stdout is redirected to) should stop. 
Then continue one of them using

```
kill -SIGCONT pid1
```

If the error messages appear immediately, you know its the first process. If not you can stop it again and continue the second...

Before killing a stopped process, it is good practise to send first SIGCONT.

The same technique can be used with `Ctrl-Z` and the shell job controls (`fg %1`, `bg %1`, `kill %1`, ...).

Comment: Thats a very good way to troubleshoot it but i was really looking for a way to trace who is writting to terminal. Thank you

Comment: Was just rereading this question, seems like I had a brain fart while writing my last comment. This would also fix my problem. Thx.